# In netbeans how do I select all currently open files in the project view

Tags: svn, netbeans, ide, workflow

How do I select the files I currently have open in the project view without trawling through the project tree and ctrl+clicking them all individually.

After editing multiple files I then want to diff and commit them using the SVN plugin. To do this currently I trawl through the project tree selecting all the files I need then right click and select diff. Seeing as it is nearly always the files I have open that I want to diff it would be nice to automatically select them in project view and save the trawling.

This is especially annoying if I miss a file as I can't seem to find a way to add it to the diff tab without redoing the whole process.

Solutions or better ways of using SVN with netbeans would be awesome :)

Many thanks, Tom

Comment: You can also exclude the files from the proyect, in case you dont want to commit all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, much better approach would be the following:

- checkout/update your project from Subversion in order to be sure that you have fresh source files
- open and change whichever file you want and save changes
- right click on `Source packages`, then `Subversion->Commit`, it will commit all changes you've made on the source code

Hope that helps.

Comment: I see what you mean however I tend to have multiple files that have been modified but only want to commit some of them. I realise this might seem messy but it does work well for me. Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: Understand, but I am not sure if it's possible to do it that way. My answer was actually referring to your sentence: 'Solutions or better ways of using SVN with netbeans would be awesome :)'

Comment: I think your right it doesn't seem to be how the SVN plugin was designed to be used. If I find time I might have a look at making my own netbeans plugin which selects all open files in the projects view. Thanks for your help :)